# Oracle - How to start OC4J instance on Windows 10

Tags: oracle, installation, windows-10, oracleforms, oc4j

I am getting the error message below when trying to run a form in Oracle Form Builder:

> FRM-10142: The HTTP Listener is not running on
> DESKTOP-AF3LCH5.lan (port 9001) . Please start the listener or
> check your runtime preferences.

In order to fix that, I have installed Oracle jDeveloper Studio as I found in the documentation on the link below that OC4J (that is provided with JDeveloper) needs to be installed first:

https://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/1012/web_services/dep_wsoc4j.html

However, I couldn't find the folder named "home" on this path: <JDeveloper_home>/j2ee/home.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Which Forms version is it?

Comment: It is 12.2.1.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to my answer to your question here:

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4495175/how-to-start-oc4j-instance-on-windows-10

Comment: I got your point. I have actually post my reply to your answer on the Oracle community. Could you please take a look at it? Here is its link:

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/16826675#Comment_16826675